# Is there a way to embed the contents of a file or partial file in javadoc

Tags: java, javadoc

When I write unit tests, I see them as both a mechanism of verifying the code behaves as intended and as documented examples of how to use the code. As such, I would love to include the contents of my test classes as examples. So something like this:

```
/**
 * Foos the bar
 * @example FooBarTest#testFooingBar()
 * @param bar The {@link Bar} to foo
 * return The fooed {@code Bar}
 */
public Bar fooBar(Bar bar)
{
   // Completely foo the bar
}
```

Then when this gets rendered one would see the content of FooBarTest.testFooingBar() in the javadoc.

I did some googling and didn't see anything. So is there any way I can do this (maven plugin perhaps)?

Answer (score 0):

I've just finished a beta version of a library that does just this. It's called Codelet. Here's the answer I just posted about it in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24516962/how-can-i-easily-display-my-example-code-in-javadoc-without-having-to-manually):

---

This is the question I've tried to answer with [Codelet](http://codelet.aliteralmind.com) ([GitHub link](https://github.com/aliteralmind/codelet)).

**Codelet** automates the insertion of *already unit-tested* example code into your JavaDoc, using taglets. As with all taglets, Codelet is executed as part of `javadoc.exe`. It is now released in beta, (and needs beta testers!).

There are four Codelet taglets:

- `{@codelet.and.out}`: Displays source code immediately followed by its output
- `{@codelet}`: Displays source code only
- `{@codelet.out}`: Displays output only
- `{@file.textlet}`: Displays the contents of any plain-text file, such as the input for an example code.

A [common example](http://aliteralmind.com/docs/computer/programming/codelet/documentation/javadoc/overview-summary.html#xmpl_hello):

`{@.codelet.and.out com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.examples.adder.AdderDemo%eliminateCommentBlocksAndPackageDecl()}`

which uses the `eliminateCommentBlocksAndPackageDecl()` "customizer" to eliminate the package declaration line and all multi-line comments (such as the license and JavaDoc blocks).

Output (between the horizontal rules):

---

#### Example

```
public class AdderDemo  {
   public static final void main(String[] ignored)  {

      Adder adder = new Adder();
      System.out.println(adder.getSum());

      adder = new Adder(5, -7, 20, 27);
      System.out.println(adder.getSum());
   }
}
```

#### Output

```
0
45
```

---

An alternative is to display only a portion of the example's code: A [*code snippet*](http://aliteralmind.com/docs/computer/programming/codelet/documentation/javadoc/overview-summary.html#xmpl_snippet):

`{@.codelet.and.out com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.examples.adder.AdderDemo%lineRange(1, false, "Adder adder", 2, false, "println(adder.getSum())", "^      ")}`

This displays the same example as above, starting with (the line containing) `Adder adder`, and ending with the *second* `println(adder.getSum())`. This also eliminates the extra indentation, which in this case is six spaces.

Output (between the horizontal rules):

---

#### Example

```
Adder adder = new Adder();
System.out.println(adder.getSum());

adder = new Adder(5, -7, 20, 27);
System.out.println(adder.getSum());
```

***Output:***

```
0
45
```

---

All taglets accept customizers.

It is possible to write your own customizers which, for example, can ["linkify" function names](http://aliteralmind.com/docs/computer/programming/codelet/documentation/javadoc/overview-summary.html#xmpl_links), change the template in which source-and-output is displayed, and do any arbitrary alteration to any or all lines. Examples include highlighting something in yellow, or making regular expression replacements.

As a final example, and as a contrast to those above, here is the taglet that blindly prints all lines from an example code, without any changes. It uses [no customizer](http://aliteralmind.com/docs/computer/programming/codelet/documentation/javadoc/overview-summary.html#xmpl_nocust):

`{@.codelet.and.out com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.examples.adder.AdderDemo}`

Output (between the horizontal rules):

---

#### Example

```
/*license*\
   Codelet: Copyright (C) 2014, Jeff Epstein (aliteralmind __DASH__ github __AT__ yahoo __DOT__ com)

   This software is dual-licensed under the:
   - Lesser General Public License (LGPL) version 3.0 or, at your option, any later version;
   - Apache Software License (ASL) version 2.0.

   Either license may be applied at your discretion. More information may be found at
   - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-licensing.

   The text of both licenses is available in the root directory of this project, under the names &quot;LICENSE_lgpl-3.0.txt&quot; and &quot;LICENSE_asl-2.0.txt&quot;. The latest copies may be downloaded at:
   - LGPL 3.0: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-3.0.txt
   - ASL 2.0: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt
\*license*/
package  com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.examples.adder;
/**
   <P>Demonstration of {@code com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.examples.adder.Adder}.</P>

   <P>{@code java com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.examples.AdderDemo}</P>

   @since  0.1.0
   @author  Copyright (C) 2014, Jeff Epstein ({@code aliteralmind __DASH__ github __AT__ yahoo __DOT__ com}), dual-licensed under the LGPL (version 3.0 or later) or the ASL (version 2.0). See source code for details. <A HREF=&quot;http://codelet.aliteralmind.com&quot;>{@code http://codelet.aliteralmind.com}</A>, <A HREF=&quot;https://github.com/aliteralmind/codelet&quot;>{@code https://github.com/aliteralmind/codelet}</A>
 **/
public class AdderDemo  {
   public static final void main(String[] ignored)  {

      Adder adder = new Adder();
      System.out.println(adder.getSum());

      adder = new Adder(5, -7, 20, 27);
      System.out.println(adder.getSum());
   }
}
```

***Output:***

```
0
45
```

---

Codelet is in beta, but is reasonably stable. Please consider giving it a try, and giving your comments and criticisms in the GitHub issue tracker.

Thanks.