# How can I display my example code in JavaDoc, without having to manually copy/paste it?

Tags: java, documentation, javadoc

I need to display my example code directly in my library's JavaDoc documentation, including its output. But I want to automate this process, so the example code can be unit tested by an external process, and *not* displayed unless it actually works.

I have not figured out a way to do this except by manually copy-pasting the source code (and output) each time a change is made--which is unmanageable given there are now well above a hundred example classes in my various projects. Alternatively I could simply *not* display those examples, but instead provide a link to them.

Both of these solutions are unacceptable, and I am hoping there might be a better way to do this.

How do you automate the insertion of your example code, so it is displayed directly in your JavaDoc?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is the question I've tried to answer with [Codelet](http://codelet.aliteralmind.com) ([GitHub link](https://github.com/aliteralmind/codelet)).

**Codelet** automates the insertion of *already unit-tested* example code into your JavaDoc, using taglets. As with all taglets, Codelet is executed as part of `javadoc.exe`. It is now released in beta, (and needs beta testers!).

There are four Codelet taglets:

- `{@codelet.and.out}`: Displays source code immediately followed by its output
- `{@codelet}`: Displays source code only
- `{@codelet.out}`: Displays output only
- `{@file.textlet}`: Displays the contents of any plain-text file, such as the input for an example code.

A [common example](http://aliteralmind.com/docs/computer/programming/codelet/documentation/javadoc/overview-summary.html#xmpl_hello):

`{@.codelet.and.out com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.examples.adder.AdderDemo%eliminateCommentBlocksAndPackageDecl()}`

which uses the `eliminateCommentBlocksAndPackageDecl()` "customizer" to eliminate the package declaration line and all multi-line comments (such as the license and JavaDoc blocks).

Output (between the horizontal rules):

---

#### Example

```
public class AdderDemo  {
   public static final void main(String[] ignored)  {

      Adder adder = new Adder();
      System.out.println(adder.getSum());

      adder = new Adder(5, -7, 20, 27);
      System.out.println(adder.getSum());
   }
}
```

#### Output

```
0
45
```

---

An alternative is to display only a portion of the example's code: A [*code snippet*](http://aliteralmind.com/docs/computer/programming/codelet/documentation/javadoc/overview-summary.html#xmpl_snippet):

`{@.codelet.and.out com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.examples.adder.AdderDemo%lineRange(1, false, "Adder adder", 2, false, "println(adder.getSum())", "^      ")}`

This displays the same example as above, starting with (the line containing) `Adder adder`, and ending with the *second* `println(adder.getSum())`. This also eliminates the extra indentation, which in this case is six spaces.

Output (between the horizontal rules):

---

#### Example

```
Adder adder = new Adder();
System.out.println(adder.getSum());

adder = new Adder(5, -7, 20, 27);
System.out.println(adder.getSum());
```

***Output:***

```
0
45
```

---

All taglets accept customizers.

It is possible to write your own customizers which, for example, can ["linkify" function names](http://aliteralmind.com/docs/computer/programming/codelet/documentation/javadoc/overview-summary.html#xmpl_links), change the template in which source-and-output is displayed, and do any arbitrary alteration to any or all lines. Examples include highlighting something in yellow, or making regular expression replacements.

As a final example, and as a contrast to those above, here is the taglet that blindly prints all lines from an example code, without any changes. It uses [no customizer](http://aliteralmind.com/docs/computer/programming/codelet/documentation/javadoc/overview-summary.html#xmpl_nocust):

`{@.codelet.and.out com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.examples.adder.AdderDemo}`

Output (between the horizontal rules):

---

#### Example

```
/*license*\
   Codelet: Copyright (C) 2014, Jeff Epstein (aliteralmind __DASH__ github __AT__ yahoo __DOT__ com)

   This software is dual-licensed under the:
   - Lesser General Public License (LGPL) version 3.0 or, at your option, any later version;
   - Apache Software License (ASL) version 2.0.

   Either license may be applied at your discretion. More information may be found at
   - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-licensing.

   The text of both licenses is available in the root directory of this project, under the names &quot;LICENSE_lgpl-3.0.txt&quot; and &quot;LICENSE_asl-2.0.txt&quot;. The latest copies may be downloaded at:
   - LGPL 3.0: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-3.0.txt
   - ASL 2.0: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt
\*license*/
package  com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.examples.adder;
/**
   <P>Demonstration of {@code com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.examples.adder.Adder}.</P>

   <P>{@code java com.github.aliteralmind.codelet.examples.AdderDemo}</P>

   @since  0.1.0
   @author  Copyright (C) 2014, Jeff Epstein ({@code aliteralmind __DASH__ github __AT__ yahoo __DOT__ com}), dual-licensed under the LGPL (version 3.0 or later) or the ASL (version 2.0). See source code for details. <A HREF=&quot;http://codelet.aliteralmind.com&quot;>{@code http://codelet.aliteralmind.com}</A>, <A HREF=&quot;https://github.com/aliteralmind/codelet&quot;>{@code https://github.com/aliteralmind/codelet}</A>
 **/
public class AdderDemo  {
   public static final void main(String[] ignored)  {

      Adder adder = new Adder();
      System.out.println(adder.getSum());

      adder = new Adder(5, -7, 20, 27);
      System.out.println(adder.getSum());
   }
}
```

***Output:***

```
0
45
```

---

Codelet is now released in beta. Please consider giving it a try, and posting your comments and criticisms in the GitHub issue tracker.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you want, but maybe another interesting approach is the documentation of the [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.com/):

They document with Markdown and integrate code samples with special annotations (described in the [Guidelines for writing Play documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Documentation)). So all the code samples can be tested before they are included in the documentation.

Their (unfortunately custom) solution to generate the docs can be found in the [play-doc GitHub repository](https://github.com/playframework/play-doc).

Comment: I am glad to know an alternative. Thank you for the information.